# Using the :e command in VIM

Tags: vim

I like to type :cd to get into a working folder and then combinations of :e, :split and :vsplit to get my working setup functional. However, since I am working with .tex files, there are often different file types generated by my .tex file at compilation (.log, .aux, etc.) within my working folder.

Is there any way to force VIM to only list the files in my directory containing certain extensions? For example, it would be great if it only displayed files of type related to programming languages such as .tex, .cpp, .cs, .py, .json, etc. The point is that I never open some file types in VIM (image files, pdf files, and so on), so I don't see why they should show up in my :e search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vim supports the exclusion and de-prioritization of certain file patterns / extensions via the `'wildignore'` and `'suffixes'` options.

Here's an example configuration (that you can put into your `~/.vimrc`) that completely ignores swap files, images, generated files, and version control system data, and puts backup files to the end of completion candidates:

```
:set wildignore=*.sw[ponm],*.gif,*.jpg,*.jpeg,*.png,*.pdf,tags,*.o,*.class,*.java.html,*.pyc,*.pyo,.bzr/,.git/,.hg/,.svn/
:set suffixes=.bak,.orig,~
```

Note that you can also specify a *file glob* for `:edit` and similar commands; `<Tab>` will then expand it; `<C-d>` will show all candidates. This allows for quick custom selection of files.

Comment: So it is like a regexp, i.e. the *.sw[ponm] is short for *.swp, *.swo, *.swn, *.swm?

Comment: Similar to a regexp, but not so powerful. The syntax is based on (e.g. Bash) file globs; see `:help file-pattern` for the full available syntax.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `'wildignore'` to set a list of file patterns which are ignored for expanding wildcards and completing file/directory names.

You can do add filename patterns to `'wildignore'` by using `+=` with `:set` in your `vimrc`. Example:

```
set wildignore+=*.o
set wildignore+=*.obj
set wildignore+=*.log
set wildignore+=*.aux
```

See `:h 'wildingore'` for more information.

You may also be interested in using `<c-d>` to list completions. This can be helpful navigation with `:e`, `:sp`, and friends. See `:h c_CTRL-D`.

Comment: Is this a bit like a regexp? I am confused about how I should implement this. Should I put in my .vimrc the filetypes I want VIM to read or am I only allowed to "ignore" certain filetypes, i.e. I should list all those that I don't want to see?